# How remove the extra space in multiple swiper tabs suitable to all media queries using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a tab slider using javascript with the tabs having fixed size.It also has to support all devices(using media query).

I have created the similar slide.But I am facing problems while viewing in mobile tab view.

I need a pattern similar to the following link:

https://www.vecteezy.com/free-vector/banner-template

[image]

I have tried.But in mobile the tabs is getting hide.last tabs are not visible.I dont know where the problem comes?

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
              slidesPerView: 6,
              slidesPerGroup: 1,
              loop: false,
              loopFillGroupWithBlank: true,
              navigation: {
                nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
              },
               breakpoints: {
          1300: {
                  slidesPerView: 8,
              },

              1199: {
                  slidesPerView: 6,
              },
              991: {
                  slidesPerView: 4,
              },
              600: {
                  slidesPerView: 2,
              },
          }
            });
```

```css
.swiper-button-prev {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'><path%20d%3D'M0%2C22L22%2C0l2.1%2C2.1L4.2%2C22l19.9%2C19.9L22%2C44L0%2C22L0%2C22L0%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23444444'%2F><%2Fsvg>") !important;
}

.swiper-button-next {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M27%2C22L27%2C22L5%2C44l-2.1-2.1L22.8%2C22L2.9%2C2.1L5%2C0L27%2C22L27%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23444444'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E") !important;
}

@media  screen and (min-width: 1200px){
    .tab_wrapper{
    width: 100%;
}
.swiper-container {
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
.swiper-wrapper {
     width: 100%;
}

}

@media  screen and (max-width: 1200px){
/*  .tab_wrapper{
    width: 600px;
}
.swiper-container {
    width: 500px;
}
.swiper-wrapper {
     width: 500px;
}*/

.tab_wrapper{
    width: 100%;
}
.swiper-container {
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
.swiper-wrapper {
     width: 100%;
}


}


.tab_wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*width: 1200px;*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.swiper-container {
    /*width: 1000px;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.swiper-wrapper {
     width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    /*width: 100%;   */
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -o-transition-property: transform;
    transition-property: transform;
    transition-property: transform,-webkit-transform;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;

}

.swiper-slide p{
    width: 100px;
}

.swiper-slide{
    border:1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
    -ms-flex-negative: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    width: auto!important;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -o-transition-property: transform;
    transition-property: transform;
    transition-property: transform,-webkit-transform;

}


.swiper-slide, .swiper-wrapper {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.swiper-button-next, .swiper-button-prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 27px;
    height: 44px;
    margin-top: -22px;
    z-index: 10;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-size: 27px 44px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.swiper-button-next{
    right:0;
}
.swiper-button-prev{
    left:0;
}

.swiper-button-next.swiper-button-disabled, .swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-disabled {
    opacity: .35;
    cursor: auto;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.1.6/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab_wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-container">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
        <p>Tab 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <p>Tab 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <p>Tab 3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <p>Tab 4</p>
        </div>

        <div class="swiper-slide">
         <p>Tab 5</p>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <p>Tab 6</p>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <p>Tab 7</p>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <p>Tab 8</p>
        </div>

         <div class="swiper-slide">
         <p>Tab 9</p>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <p>Tab 10</p>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <p>Tab 11</p>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <p>Tab 12</p>
        </div>
         <div class="swiper-slide">
          <p>Tab 13</p>
        </div>
         <div class="swiper-slide">
          <p>Tab 14</p>
        </div>
         <div class="swiper-slide">
          <p>Tab 15</p>
        </div>
         <div class="swiper-slide">
          <p>Tab 16</p>
        </div>
         <div class="swiper-slide">
          <p>Tab 17</p>
        </div>
         <div class="swiper-slide">
          <p>Tab 18</p>
        </div>
         <div class="swiper-slide">
          <p>Tab 19</p>
        </div>
         <div class="swiper-slide">
          <p>Tab 20</p>
        </div>

      </div>
      
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>

</div>
```

[image]

In my mobile view the 20th tab is not visible while clicking next button.Please help how to dispaly all tabs in mobile and tab view?

Also empty space appears in the last after 20th tab.I sholud automatically get fixed to the outer container when multiple tabs are added.